# SQL update statement not updating all expected row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement to grab all products

```
SELECT *  
FROM Products AS P
INNER JOIN Suppliers AS S ON S.product_id = P.product_id
```

This returns 560 rows. But when I try updating all those rows, it says 225 rows updated instead of 560:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.hasSupplier = 1
FROM Products AS P
INNER JOIN Suppliers AS S ON S.product_id = P.product_id
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query has suppliers that have more than one product.  Only one of these rows is updated in the second query.

You can run:

```
select count(*), count(distinct productid)
from suppliers;
```

To see the difference.

I would recommend using `exists` for the `update`:

```
UPDATE P
    SET P.hasSupplier = 1
    FROM Products P
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Suppliers S WHERE S.product_id = P.product_id);
```